# Pick a key-value pair from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array that looks like this

```
[
  "---\n",
  ":date: 2018-07-31\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-01\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-22\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "
]
```

I want to pick all the values of the key `":date"`. I read that I can use `Enumerable#select`, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You will always have a soln but may i ask who is generating this array. may be you can tweak it to use it like hash or something more meaningful.

Comment: Where did you get this array? It looks like you split a YAML file on new lines when you should have just `YAML.parse`’ed the file and then you’d have proper hashes and arrays.

Comment: Let's try the given solution below if your array is like this .

Comment: The array is a result from the database. I have a Text column in database which stores all these information in a single column. I have brought it to the application layer and now I need to group by date column and proceed with further functionality.

Comment: I will try the solutions below and let you know. Thanks for the help

Comment: `arr.grep(/date/).map { |s| s[7..16] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = ["---\n",
       ":date: 2018-07-31\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
       ":date: 2018-08-01\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
       ":date: 2018-08-22\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "]
```

```
arr.join.scan(/:date: (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/).flatten
  #=> ["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
```

or

```
arr.join.scan(/(?<=:date: )\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).flatten
  #=> ["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
```

`(?<=:date: )` being a positive lookbehind,

or

```
arr.join.gsub(/(?<=:date: )\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).to_a
  #=> ["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
```

This last option looks a bit odd because I am using `gsub` merely to create an enumerator that generates matches to a regular expression. This is the result when [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html) has a single argument and no block. In such situations the name`"gsub"` is misleading, as there is no substitution of strings with other strings. Think of that form of the method being called `match_all`. I have found many uses for this form of `gsub`.

Comment: Perhaps, the OP wants to apply `flatten` to the results, but that is trivial.

Comment: change to `arr.join.scan(/:date: (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/).flatten` to match OP's expected result

Answer (score 1):

One might use [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with regular expression argument and [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
input.flat_map { |e| e[/(?<=:date:\s).*/] }.compact
#⇒ ["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks a heck of a lot like `YAML` (although it needs a little sanitizing) I would go with:

```
a = [
  "---\n",
  ":date: 2018-07-31\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-01\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-22\n  :estimated_hours: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "
].map(&:rstrip)

require 'yaml'

data = a[1..-1].map {|s| YAML.load(s.gsub("  ", ""))}
#=> [
#  {:date=>#<Date: 2018-07-31 ((2458331j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :estimated_hours=>4.0, :remaining_hours=>4.0}, 
#  {:date=>#<Date: 2018-08-01 ((2458332j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :estimated_hours=>4.0, :remaining_hours=>4.0}, 
#  {:date=>#<Date: 2018-08-22 ((2458353j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :estimated_hours=>4.0, :remaining_hours=>0.0}]

data.map {|h| h[:date] } 
#=> [#<Date: 2018-07-31 ((2458331j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 
#     #<Date: 2018-08-01 ((2458332j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 
#     #<Date: 2018-08-22 ((2458353j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
data = ["---\n", ":date: 2018-07-31\n :estimated_hours: 4.0\n :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ", ":date: 2018-08-01\n :estimated_hours: 4.0\n :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ", ":date: 2018-08-22\n :estimated_hours: 4.0\n :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "]

DATE_REGEX = /:date:\s(.*)\n/

dates = data.map do |record|
  record.match(DATE_REGEX)[1] if record.match(REGEX)
end.compact
```

Comment: Don’t you need `/:date:\s(.*)?\n/` (`?` to make the match of the capture group non-greedy, so the match will end at the first (not last) newline in the string)?